# PostgreSQL query for Library Management System

Tags: sql, postgresql

Get the member ID and name of the members to whom no more books can be issued, because they have already got as many books issued as the number for which they are entitled

Following are the schemas:

```
Book_Records(accession_no,isbn_no)
Book(isbn_no, author, publisher, price)
Members(member_id, member_name,max_no_books,max_no_days)
Book_Issue(member_id,accession_no,issue_date,return_date)
```

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK (ISBN_NO VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY, 
                   AUTHOR VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
                   PUBLISHER VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
                   PRICE NUMERIC(10,3));
```

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_RECORDS(ACCESSION_NO VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY, 
              ISBN_NO VARCHAR(35) REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN_NO));
```

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY,
             MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
             MAX_NO_BOOKS INT,
             MAX_NO_DAYS INT);
```

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_ISSUE(MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(35) REFERENCES MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID),
                        ACCESSION_NO VARCHAR(35) REFERENCES 
                        BOOK_RECORDS(ACCESSION_NO),
                        ISSUE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
                        RETURN_DATE DATE,
                        PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID,ACCESSION_NO));
```

I tried the following query but fails.

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_name 
FROM members AS m 
  JOIN ( 
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS no_books_issued 
    FROM book_issue 
    GROUP BY member_id,accesion_no 
    HAVING no_books_issued >= max_no_books
  ) AS b ON m.member_id = b.member_id;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - please provide as much detail as possible when asking questions, it will help other members to answer your question. Please include any error messages in your question detail.

Comment: in your query what does max_no_books relate to?

Comment: max_no_books  – Maximum Number of books that can be issued   max max_no_days  – Maximum Number of days for which book can be issued

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, a query like this gets the number of books currently issued:

```
SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS num_books
FROM book_issue 
WHERE return_date IS NULL
GROUP BY member_id;
```

My understanding of the maximum number of books would be concurrently -- that is, only count books that have not been returned.  Perhaps you have a different definition.

Then, you can use this in a `JOIN`, doing the  comparison on the maximum *outside* the subquery:

```
SELECT member_name 
FROM members m JOIN
    (SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS num_books 
     FROM book_issue 
     WHERE return_date IS NULL
     GROUP BY member_id
    ) b
    ON b.member_id = m.member_id AND
       b.num_books >= m.max_no_books;
```

Notes:

- In a `JOIN`, the comparison to the outer table needs to be *outside* the subqueries.
- No `SELECT DISTINCT` is needed.
- The `GROUP BY` for counting books should be only at the member level.

Comment: The original query would be valid when using a `lateral join` in that case it would be allowed to access columns of the outer query in the derived table